# Setting data frame to match exact borders of map using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, data-frame

I would like to have the border of the data frame to fit exactly the maps that are shown inside, so in other words, I want to get rid of blank spaces.

I know, this is possible by dragging the borders and moving the map inside the frame with the handle but I am looking for another option for layout purposes.

Is there a preset option for this ?

[image: the frame I am trying to move]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use two more options, using the data in my maps to drive the data frame extent:

- Clip the dataframe (help on this is [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/clipping-the-data-frame.htm)), here's a screenshot of how I set the dataframe parameter window:
  [image]
- Fixed, rectangle extent matching the bounding box of an object in the map. (some limited help on this is [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/customizing-your-map-extent.htm)), here's a screenshot of how I set the dataframe parameter window:
  [image]

Comment: Thanks, it's the clipping part I was after. I had tried setting a fixed scale but this did only scale my map but not get rid of the blanks in the dataframe !

Comment: @Oh-No : Happy to hep! if you could please mark the answer as accepted, then, it would be great! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the extent by changing the scale from `Automatic` to `Fixed Scale` from the data frame first. To do that right-click the data frame in the `layout view -> Properties -> Data Frame -> Extent -> change Automatic to Fixed Scale or Fixed Extent` you can choose which one is easier for you.

[image]

In this example I chose `Fixed Scale`

[image]

Then you need to resize the frame to the desired size and use `Pan` to move the view to show/hide any portion of the map.

Before Fixing the scale:

[image]

Before Fixing the scale (Resize Frame and Pan):

[image]

Comment: What about rotation? My layer is also a little bit rotated, i followed your steps but when it fits it is a regular square, i want it even rotated.